# Custom remote event handling in app from iOS lock screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, uiresponder

How does spotify handle custom remote events? Currently on iPhone 6 running iOS 8.1.3 and spotify version 2.4.0.1822 I get the following controls on the lock screen when I turn on spotify radio. Ive tried reading all docs pertaining to remote events, and I'm unable to find any resources which allow custom remote events from the lock screen.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe that is implemented with MPRemoteCommandCenter.
Here is example...

```
MPRemoteCommandCenter *remoteCommandCenter = [MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter];
[[remoteCommandCenter skipForwardCommand] addTarget:self action:@selector(skipForward)];
[[remoteCommandCenter togglePlayPauseCommand] addTarget:self action:@selector(togglePlayPause)];
[[remoteCommandCenter pauseCommand] addTarget:self action:@selector(pause)];
[[remoteCommandCenter likeCommand] addTarget:self action:@selector(like)];
```

Implement this code, play music on your app, and lock your iPhone. You will probably see a customized lock screen.

**Note** - Menu can be customized label, but it can not customize icon image and number of row.

Comment: @kalpa Simulator doesn't support Control Center now.
So, you can not see this function on Simulator.